# set NSButton position inside NSTableView to center programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, position, nstableview, nstablecellview

Is it possible to set the "position" value (see image below) programmatically instead of using `IB`?
I would need to set it like the one in the image. 
I've been searching for a solution for a while now without luck.

[image: POSITION]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that setting applies to button images and corresponds to imagePosition property of NSButton

Comment: yayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy thank youuu! sorry for the delay was veeeery busy! thank you very much!!!